# Mac OS 10.7.5 BSD copyfile() EINVAL when copying files having double-quotes in the name

Tags: c, macos, bsd, file-management

I'm trying to use BSD copyfile(...) to copy a file to a mounted AFP share (/Volumes/exchange) with an Obj-C++ code like this:

Minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <copyfile.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int copyfile_callback(int what, int stage, copyfile_state_t state, const char * src, const char * dst, void * ctx);
void copy_file(const std::string& src, const std::string& dst);
NSString* StringToNSString ( const std::string& Str );

int main ()
{
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
    id window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
            autorelease];
    [window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20,20)];
    [window setTitle:appName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    copy_file(
      "copyfile.mm",
      "/Volumes/exchange/filename(\"[~!@#$%^&*,.']\").MP4"
    );

    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}

void copy_file(const std::string& fromPath, const std::string& toPath)
{
    NSLog(@"copyfile: %s -> %s", fromPath.c_str(), toPath.c_str());
    copyfile_state_t s = copyfile_state_alloc();
    copyfile_state_set(s, COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB, (void*)&copyfile_callback);
    int returnCode = copyfile(fromPath.c_str(), toPath.c_str(), s, COPYFILE_ALL);
    if( returnCode ) {
        NSLog(@"copyfile error code: %d, errno=%d", returnCode, errno);
    }
    copyfile_state_free(s);
}

int copyfile_callback(int what, int stage, copyfile_state_t state, const char * src, const char * dst, void * ctx)
{
    bool bContinue = true;
    switch( what ) {
        case COPYFILE_COPY_DATA:
            if( stage == COPYFILE_PROGRESS ) {
                int src_fd;
                off_t bytes_completed = 0L, total_bytes = 0L;
                copyfile_state_get(state, COPYFILE_STATE_COPIED, (void*)&bytes_completed);
                copyfile_state_get(state, COPYFILE_STATE_SRC_FD, (void*)&src_fd);
                struct stat fstat_info;
                if( src_fd > 0 && 0 == fstat(src_fd, &fstat_info) ) {
                    total_bytes = fstat_info.st_size;
                }
                NSLog(@"copyfile_callback: Copied %lld/%lld bytes so far.", bytes_completed, total_bytes);

            } else if( stage == COPYFILE_ERR ) {
                NSLog(@"copyfile: COPYFILE_COPY_DATA COPYFILE_ERR");
                bContinue = false;
            }
            break;
        case COPYFILE_ERR:
            bContinue = false;
            break;
    }
    return bContinue ? COPYFILE_CONTINUE : COPYFILE_QUIT;
}

NSString* StringToNSString ( const std::string& Str )
{
    NSString *pString = [NSString stringWithCString:Str.c_str()
                                           encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]
                        ];
    return pString;
}
```

Save this example as `copyfile.mm` and compile with:

```
g++ -framework Cocoa -x objective-c++ copyfile.mm -o copyfile
```

It works fine unless my destination filename (toPath) contains a double-quote symbols. Then i get

```
returnCode == -1;
errno == 22; // EINVAL
```

It also works with normal C++, but fails with Obj-C++. With Obj-C++ - I also see the following message in the system.log:

```
5/21/13 11:47:51.314 PM myAppName: open on /Volumes/exchange/filename("[~!@#$%^&*,.']").MP4: Invalid argument
```

Mac OS 10.7.5 and gcc 4.2.1:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~148/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~148/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

Comment: It works when I try it with `copyfile("x.c", "filename(\"[~!@#$%^&*,.']\").MP4", s, COPYFILE_ALL)` on an AFP volume. You should show a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, i tried with SSCCE C++ file compiled with g++ and it also works for me. The problem arises when i call this from Obj-C++. I'm not very good with 'xcodebuild', so it'll take some time to provide proper SSCCE...

Comment: @EricPostpischil i've added minimal example, please check

Comment: Which OS version and compiler and compiler version are you using? (Note that `g++` may not be the GNU C++ compiler.)

Comment: @GregParker gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00) on Mac OS 10.7.5

Comment: @2can: Your source code works for me with no changes. I hypothesize the host system providing your AFP volume does not support quotation marks in file names. (Is it a Microsoft Windows host?) You might test with a different host. I suppose you might have to avoid using quotation marks in file names.

Comment: @EricPostpischil could be... i didn't think about that, thanks for pointing this out. I'll check my AFP share - it is netatalk-2.0.3-249.14 on linux ext3 volume btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed by Eric Postpischil (thanks!) - it was a problem with network share. After upgrading to latest netatalk version and setting correct setting to netatalk config my code works without any changes.

(sorry for late reply, guys :)